# How can i add button to each record for edit and saving to data base , i am new to apex.can anyone guide me, thanks in advance

Tags: apex, visualforce

Here i am trying to add html button to each record using repeat tag.Here  i added two buttons(for edit and save) but both are working on the same record.
code i have wrote:

```
<script>
  function buttonName()
  {
      //alert("i am in button name");
      var elem = document.getElementById("mybutton1");
      if (elem.value=="Edit")
                    elem.value = "Save";
      else 
                   elem.value = "Edit";

  }
 function result()
 {
     //alert("Start");

      if(document.getElementById("mytest").value=="")
     {
        // alert("initial edit"); 
            buttonName();  

     var spanresultText = document.getElementById('spantext').innerHTML;
     document.getElementById("mytest").value=spanresultText ;
     document.getElementById("mytest").style.display = "inline"; 
    document.getElementById("spantext").style.display= "none";       

    }else
      {

        if(document.getElementById("mytest").value == document.getElementById('spantext').innerHTML )
        {

        // alert("value not changed")
            buttonName();
            var elem = document.getElementById("mybutton1");
            if (elem.value=="Edit") {
              document.getElementById("mytest").style.display = "none"; 
             document.getElementById("spantext").style.display= "inline"; 
                }else{
                        document.getElementById("mytest").style.display = "inline"; 
                        document.getElementById("spantext").style.display= "none"; 
                    }

        }
        else{
              //alert("value changed");
              buttonName();
              var samptext=document.getElementById("mytest").value;
               //alert(samptext);
              document.getElementById("spantext").innerHTML=samptext;
              document.getElementById("mytest").style.display = "none"; 
             document.getElementById("spantext").style.display= "inline"; 

            }
      }            
 }

</script>
 <apex:form >

    <apex:repeat value="{!acc}" var="string" id="theRepeat">
     <div>
        <br/><br/><span style="color:red;size:30;display:inline;" id ="spantext" >{!string.name}</span>
        <span ><input type="text" id="mytest" style="display:none;color:red;" /></span>      
    <input type="submit" id="mybutton1" value="Edit" onclick = "result();return false;"  style="display:inline;"/>
     </div>
  </apex:repeat>
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to the community, it would be great if you can explain your question in detail. when you say same record what does it mean. I can see that you have only single rendered record instead of multiple one.

Comment: Hi Himanshu,thank for reply.Here as shown in the image i got two records from backend and assigned buttons(record values "wefwef" and "ssss"). if i click on the edit button which was assigned to "ssss" record  but the action is happening on "wefwef" record only.but i need to edit "ssss" record whenever i click second edit button...

Comment: here  i am using controller which is getting two records from standard account . i hope you understand what i was said above. i need to add buttons to  each individual record(using repeat tag) for edit and save.

Comment: it is because you have defined a single method called result(); I am assuming that method is actionfunction ?

Comment: No Himanshu , it is java script function.

Comment: I don't see any save button in your code ?

Comment: Thank you once again Himanshu, here i am changing the button name dynamically. here is my code check it

Comment: I have updated the code , can you please check it once

Comment: Here in this code i didn't write the code for saving updated record into database.i wrote for only to edit text.this action is taking place on single(i mean first record). I need this action to be work on multiple records. help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is some basic issue with your code. If you will try to execute it line by line yourself you will understand the issue. here is what I found.

you are assigning same id="mytest" for all the buttons same id ="spantext"  for all the span. it means when you access that using javascript it finds 10 id if loop running 10 times which is not good.

Try to define css class to all buttons and use css class as selector using jquery to read the data of button, text or any other item. It will be very hard for anybody to write a whole code so I am giving you basic idea what you can do to make your code work.

Your code should look like this

Javascript:

```
//use css selector instead of ID
$( ".btnClass" ).click(function() {
     //you can now write your logic here.
     var recordid = $(this).attr('id');
     //to get textvalue
     document.getElementById('mytest_' + recordid);

});
```

Visualforce page:

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!acc}" var="string" id="theRepeat">
 <div>
    <br/><br/><span style="color:red;size:30;display:inline;" id ="spantext_{!acc.id}" >{!string.name}</span>
    <span ><input type="text" id="mytest_{!acc.id}" style="display:none;color:red;" /></span>      
<input type="submit" class="btnClass" id="acc_{!acc.id}" value="Edit" style="display:inline;"/>
 </div>
```

if you will run this code now it will generate unique id for every single item which you can use for processing.

Makes sense?

Comment: I understood Himanshu, i will try this once. Thank you somuch....